# capture h264 to buffer with openCV

Tags: opencv, stream, h.264

I retrieve an rtp H264 stream. I process like this :
- get Udp packet
- remove rtp header and parse packet to get image
- record/append image into a file
- open this file with opencv (bool VideoCapture::open(const string& filename))

and all is working fine!!

Now I want to skip the record in the file step and directly send image from udp process to opencv. But i don't know how initialise opencv with an input buffer. It only accept const string& filename.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if it's single images, you got in memory, [imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) should do the trick